# Convert string to a linkedlist in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

This is how I am defining my linkedList

```
class ListNode(object):
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None
```

I am trying to convert a string to a linkedList

```
stringTotal = "abc"
head = stringToListNode(stringTotal)

#this method should return a -> b -> c 
def stringToListNode(stringTotal):
    for i in stringTotal:
        currentNode = ListNode(i)
```

How can I get the next letter of the string and make it the next node?

Comment: Just use a temporary variable to store the last seen node, and set its next to the current node.

Comment: Also, don't you want to return the first node, not the last node as the head?  In fact, you don't return anything right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```python
def stringToListNode(stringTotal):
    previousNode = None
    first = None
    for i in stringTotal:
        currentNode = ListNode(i)
        if first is None:
            first = currentNode
        if previousNode is not None:
            previousNode.next = currentNode
        previousNode = currentNode
    return first
```

Comment: This is a good, clean (enough) edit to the original function, but I think making it a classmethod is cleaner overall

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to do this might be to define a `from_string` classmethod on your `ListNode` class that will recursively build a linked list for you and return the head:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s):
        if s:
            n = cls(s[0])
            n.next = ListNode.from_string(s[1:])
            return n

n = ListNode.from_string('hello')
print(n.next.next.next.next.val)
>>> 'o'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an `insert` method as an attribute of `ListNode`, that can be called on the `next` attribute should that latter already store a node of `ListNode`:

```
class ListNode(object):
   def __init__(self, x=None):
     self.val = x
     self.next = None
   def insert(self, val):
     if self.val is None:
        self.val = val
     else:
        getattr(self.next, 'insert', lambda x:setattr(self, 'next', ListNode(x)))(val)
   def __str__(self):
     return '{}, {}'.format(self.val, str(self.next) if self.next else '')
   def __repr__(self):
     return 'List(<{}>)'.format(str(self))
   @classmethod
   def insert_vals(cls, s):
     l = cls()
     for i in s:
       l.insert(i)
     return l

_list = ListNode.insert_vals('abc')
print(_list)
```

Output:

```
List(<a, b, c, >)
```

Note, however, that the operation accomplished in method `insert` can also be performed as a simple function, however, it is not as clean as an instance attribute:

```
class ListNode(object):
  def __init__(self, x=None):
    self.val = x
    self.next = None
  def __str__(self):
    return '{}, {}'.format(self.val, str(self.next) if self.next else '')
  def __repr__(self):
    return 'List(<{}>)'.format(str(self))

def insert_val(_l:ListNode, value:str) -> None:
  if _l.val is None:
    _l.val = value
  else:
    if isinstance(_l.next, ListNode):
      insert_val(_l.next, value)
    else:
      _l.next = ListNode(value)

_l = ListNode()
for i in 'abc':
  insert_val(_l, i)

>>>_l
```

Output:

```
List(<a, b, c, >)
```